# Redis WAIT behavior upon failover

Tags: redis, wait

I have a Redis HA deployment with 3 nodes (1 Master, 2 Slaves) and a sentinel running on every node. On the client side, I use a WAIT 2 0 to block indefinitely until my write reached the 2 slaves (and I am OK with that).

What would be the behavior of the WAIT command upon:

1) a network partition isolates the master and the client from the 2 slaves so my client is currently blocked by the WAIT

2) the majority of sentinels elects one of the slave as the new master (since there is still a quorum)

3) the network partition heals and the old master become slave of the new one

Would the WAIT still be blocking? Or would it release the client returning "0" slaves reached?

Many thanks